# In SQL/PHP, using SELECT statement in the exec function issue

Tags: php, sql

I am making an email validation form for my website, and I need to check if an email (stored in the variable `$email`) and a key (var `$key`) correspond to a row in the table '`confirm`' of my database.

So here is the code:

```
$check_key = $bdd -> exec("SELECT * FROM confirm WHERE 'email' = '$email' AND 'key' = '$key' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

To check if `$chek_key` has been filled up with the row in question, I try to display its content with:

```
while ($datas= $check_key->fetch()){
        echo $data['key'];}
```

But nothing appears...

I also tried to change the quotes in the request, like this:

```
$check_key = $bdd -> query("SELECT * FROM confirm WHERE 'email' = '$email' AND 'key' = '$key' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

But I get this error:

> Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '@hotmail.com AND 'key' = 43a1e442c3efdd259102f5d80af87e9c LIMIT 1'

I'm stuck here, do you have any idea ?

Thanks

Comment: To quote your field use ` instead of '

Comment: Use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection attack.

Comment: Ok, with the "SELECT * FROM confirm WHERE email = `$mail` AND cles = `$key` LIMIT 1" I get error "Unknown column address_in_db@hotmail.fr" in "where" clause

Comment: @JohnnyH You need quotes around `$mail` and `$key`.

Comment: But it would be best to convert to prepared statements with placeholders, then you won't run into that issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To quote a column name you use backticks, not single quotes, because single quotes create string literals.

```
$check_key = $bdd -> query("SELECT * FROM confirm WHERE `email` = '$email' AND `key` = '$key' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

You should also stop using the `mysql_XXX` extension. It has been deprecated for many years, and has been removed entirely from PHP 7.0. You should use PDO or mysqli, and use prepared statements to avoid SQL injection.

Comment: Thanks, the problem was the backticks

Answer (score 0):

A proper mysql statement don't use  quote for column name

```
"SELECT * FROM confirm WHERE email = '$email' AND `key` = '$key' LIMIT 1"
```

and as suggested by barmar  use backtics for reserved  word like key

Comment: I've just tried your solution, still nothing appears when using fetch() function, yet I have double checked in my database that the values should match

Comment: You have asked  for a sintax error ..and my answer is for this question  so  this is solved or not? ..

Comment: `key` is a reserved word, it needs to be in backticks.

Answer (score 0):

Replace code

```
$check_key = $bdd -> exec("SELECT * FROM confirm WHERE 'email' = '$email' AND 'key' = '$key' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

With

```
 $check_key = $bdd -> exec("SELECT * FROM confirm WHERE email = '$email' AND key = '$key' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());
```

and

```
while ($datas= $check_key->fetch()){
        echo $data['key'];}
```

With

```
while ($data= $check_key->fetch()){
        echo $data['key'];}
```

Comment: Sorry, but I made a mistake in my post, I already put data without s for both, but still nothing appears.

Comment: `key` is a reserved word, you need to put it in backticks.